# Simple SQL 2 Tables data grouping

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to complete the following task in SQL:
Show the employment status in individual offices of the company in the following layout: office code, country, number of employees.

Table employees:
[image]

Table offices:
[image]

My idea was:

```
SELECT officeCode, (SELECT country FROM offices), COUNT(*)
FROM employees
GROUP BY officeCode
```

But it seems it doesn't work... Can you help?

Comment: `(SELECT country FROM offices)` is returning a list of countries (and the USA is in it for at lease 3 times!). On that place in a SQL query a fieldname is expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main data set would be the office. Join to the employee's table by the office code. Then from your main table, get the data you need and then do a count( employee number)
Remember to add all the fields that you are displaying to the group by.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Seems like it works properly. Can you please check if I'm am not missing something in query?

SELECT offices.officeCode, country, COUNT(*)
FROM offices
INNER JOIN employees ON employees.officeCode = offices.officeCode
GROUP BY 1, 2

Comment: It would help if you enunciated the fields. On the group by. At the group by SQL doesn't recognize the select level clause or expressions. So group by office code, country